# Highcharts solidgauge : How can I disable gradient fill?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, gauge

I'm trying to use `Highcharts` new `solidgauge` plugin.

http://jsfiddle.net/4zVU8/2/

**source code as provided by highchart**

The gauge accepts three STEP parameters to show different color based on the Data. The problem is that it displays color in gradient and I wanted

1) **Green** color upto say 20%

2) **yellow** upto 80% and

3) once value crosses 80% gauge color should be **Red**.

Is it possible?

Comment: Are you updating the value dynamically?  Why not just set the color in the options based on your value?

Comment: the values are dynamic and so as the stop colours. However user may want to see red colour only when value crosses 90% and not maroon colour when value approaches 70% in gradient.

Comment: You mean that animation form color A to B is gradient? Because it seems to be solid after animation.

Comment: what I was looking for is that colour stays green from 0 to 20 aftward is yellow upto 80 and red afterwards. However, in reality it changes from dark green to light green, yellow, gold, maroon and then red.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a solid color, set the `minColor` and `maxColor` [options](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.minColor) to the same value.  To set the color based on a value, just compare in the options:

```
var guageValue = 60;

var gaugeOptions = {

  ...

yAxis: {
    minColor: guageValue >= 80 ? '#FF0000' : (guageValue >= 60 ? '#FFFF00' : '#00FF00'),
    maxColor: guageValue >= 80 ? '#FF0000' : (guageValue >= 60 ? '#FFFF00' : '#00FF00'),
    lineWidth: 0,

    ....
```

**EDITS FOR COMMENT**

Well, doing it dynamically according to the API should be as easy as:

```
var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
var point = chart.series[0].points[0];
var color = newGuageValue >= 80 ? '#FF0000' : (newGuageValue >= 60 ? '#FFFF00' : '#00FF00');
chart.yAxis[0].update({minColor:color, maxColor:color});
point.update(newGuageValue);
```

But, this breaks the chart (and I believe it to be a bug in the library).

So the best I can come up with is to go after the internals directly:

```
var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
var point = chart.series[0].points[0];
var color = newGuageValue >= 80 ? [255,0,0,1] : (newGuageValue >= 60 ? [255,255,0,1] : [0,255,0,1]);
chart.yAxis[0].stops[0].color.rgba = color;
chart.yAxis[0].stops[1].color.rgba = color;
point.update(newGuageValue);
```

Here's a fiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BhQ5v/1/).

Comment: Although this works with static data I can't seems to make it work for dynamic data. I have setinterval which pull data every few sec/min and changing `chart.yAxis.maxColor = newVal >= 80 ? '#FF0000' : (newVal >= 60 ? '#FFFF00' : '#00FF00');` doesn't seems to work

Comment: @siddhantKumar, see response below. Seems like it works and would be preferred to mine.

Comment: Its all subjective. I can't create arrays for each color range. so your solution fits my need. thanks once again.

Answer (score 9):

You can set stops, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4zVU8/5/

```
        stops: [
            [0.0, '#55BF3B'], // green
            [0.2, '#55BF3B'], // green
            [0.21, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
            [0.80, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
            [0.81, '#DF5353'], // red
            [1, '#DF5353'] // red
        ]
```

So aright after color ends set new color.

Comment: Not sure how I missed this, much better solution then mine!

Comment: This is still giving a gradually changing gradient color, how can I change it to a categorized color theme

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean. Do you want to remove color change during the animation? This is default animation in Highcharts. You can wrap `series.drawPoints` to change how to animate it, but this will require some coding. Here is a simple example how to remove color-tweening: http://jsfiddle.net/4zVU8/64/ (color now is changed to the new color right after new value is set, before the animation).

Comment: Value 0.805 (161 km/h) is still orange though.

Comment: Stops can be exactly the same: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bwd29xos/

Answer (score 0):

```
// change your stops ,0 and 1 set the same value
var showNumber = 100; // your random data
var tickMaxNumber = 1000; // The yAxis max value 
if(showNumber <= tickMaxNumber*0.2){
    gaugeOptions.yAxis[0].stops = [ // red
        [0, '#EE4B4B'],
        [1, '#EE4B4B']
    ];
}else if(showNumber <= tickMaxNumber*0.8){
    gaugeOptions.yAxis[0].stops = [ // yellow
        [0, '#FFC063'],
        [1, '#FFC063']
    ];
}else{
    gaugeOptions.yAxis[0].stops = [ // green
        [0, '#40A276'],
        [1, '#40A276']
    ];
}

$('#container-speed').highcharts(gaugeOptions);
```